# Как создать median image?

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cJwNoUxIBzM/WZTDpw3ru6I/AAAAAAAAB8s/N-KkDRo5NKkoXEqvXOlN1GUEWbpoyyZUQCLcBGAs/s1600/image17.gif

С помощью каких фреймворков/методов можно добиться создания median image как в гифке по ссылке?
Скажите мне их названия, чтоб я мог прогуглить.

А если будут идеи c помощью чего можно сделать estimated watermark, буду вообще признателен)

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick.

```
convert *.tif -evaluate-sequence median output.tif
```

см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840556/how-do-i-calculate-the-median-of-a-stack-of-images-with-imagemagick